# Partially freeze window. why it is happening?

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze

Why one part of a window in a specific software freezes and will not go away until I close it and open it again?
I mean like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually caused by your display drivers for your Graphics Card.

Make sure that you have installed all updates, and check the provider of the Graphic card for later versions.

If all else fails, you can reduce your hardware acceleration:

- Right click on the desktop and select select Screen Resolution
- On the window that opens up, click on the Advanced Settings link
- Select the Troubleshoot tab, then click Change Settings
- Move the Hardware acceleration slider towards none to reduce or turn off video hardware acceleration. d. Click OK, and then click Restart Now.